# Different between jump and jump and link

Tags: mips

Could someone provide an example of the usefulness of the jal instruction can how it can be used to return to the main body after completing a subroutine?

regards

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"jmp" is a "goto".

"jal" is a "gosub"

jal saves the return address in $ra, should you wish to return from whence you came ;)

http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm

Answer (score 8):

Jump places a certain address in the program counter and continues execution from there, however, JAL(jump and link) does the same but it saves the return address in ra so that you can continue execution after your subroutine finishes ie:

```
int main() {
    dosomething();
    //code here
}


void dosomething() {
//.....code here
}
```

`dosomething` would be a subroutine that returns to the main block and continues executing

Answer (score 2):

jump and link will do the jump to the routine and store the program counter into GPR r31, and when the routine finishes MIPS uses 'jr r31' to return from that routine.